# By +ing vs. Ing

Tags: prepositions, gerund-clauses

Yesterday, the guy I was conversing with,  told me that he is good at  speaking English. Hearing it,  I asked him right away  "**why are we wasting our time speaking in Hindi.** (no offence to my mother tongue).

As I said it, I felt that I should have added "by" before using "ing" for example: "why are we wasting our time **by**
speaking in Hindi.

I looked it up on Google and found out that the **ing** here is a **gerund**. But I don't know when to use gerund . I could not fathom the appropriate usage of it as the rules have been vaguely described.

So my question is :

A. Is there any difference between these two sentences?

B. Can I use ing without **by** preposition without affecting the meaning?

Answer (score 1):

A) Yes, and I'll explain it in B).

B) It seems to me that using **by** in these phrases you wrote only emphasize the way you'll be doing the thing. For example:

> *Why are we wasting our time speaking in Hindi.*
>   
> Straightforward phrase. No running around the context; you're saying it the way you see it.
>   
>   *Why are we wasting our time **by** speaking in Hindi.*
>   
> You're explicitly telling your audience the way you'll be wasting time: **by** speaking in Hindi.

So you see, adding **by** in the phrase allows the receiver to explicitly see the way of how you'll be doing the previous action. But that's a bit redundant, if you ask me.